# Using Google Cloud SDK 2.X with Apache Beam

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform

I am in new project using ***Google-Cloud-Platform*** and I have to use BigTable in this project.

I want to know if i have to use the Java SDK 1.x or 2.x (with Apache Beam).

Answer (score 3):

The Dataflow v1 and Beam / Dataflow v2 both have a Cloud Bigtable connector: BigtableIO.  Here's the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/bigtable-io) which only covers Dataflow v1 for now, and you can see the javadoc for the Beam version in [this java file](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigtable/BigtableIO.java).

There is also an HBase oriented connector called CloudBigtableIO that is external to the Beam/Dataflow SDK.  [Here](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/dataflow-hbase) is the official doc for that connector.

FYI, I am the author of CloudBigtableIO and the Cloud Bigtable java client.

Comment: i have tried Dataflow v1 bit it didn't work work, i got this error : java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.grpc.internal.GrpcUtil.getThreadFactory(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory;

Comment: If you use Dataflow v1, only include the bigtable-hbase-dataflow artifact, and don't include any other bigtable-hbase artifact.  There were some weird conflicts between artifacts.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's a new project, i will use 2.x Apache Beam version, i think it's better to stay updated.

Comment: i'm trying to use the HBase oriented connector, but i'm getting this error  : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.adapters.read.ScanAdapter.adapt(Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Scan;Lcom/google/cloud/bigtable/hbase/adapters/read/ReadHooks;)Lcom/google/bigtable/repackaged/com/google/bigtable/v2/ReadRowsRequest$Builder;
        at com.google.cloud.bigtable.beam.CloudBigtableScanConfiguration$Builder.build(CloudBigtableScanConfiguration.java:157)

Comment: If you're going to use the HBase connector, then you can only use the `bigtable-hbase-beam` artifact.  Do not use any other artifact that starts with `bigtable-hbase`.